# Python Saving Attachments from Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to automate some python code that will automatically save some attachments from certain emails with a specific title.

Below is what I currently have:

```
import win32com.client as client

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
inbox = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
target_subject = 'Testing attachment'
mail_items = [item for item in inbox.Items if item.Class == 43]
filtered = [item for item in mail_items if item.Subject == target_subject]


if len(filtered) != 0:
    target_email = filtered[0]
    

if target_email.Attachments.Count > 0:
    attachments = target_email.Attachments    
    

save_path = 'C:'

for file in attachments:
    file.SaveAsFile(save_path.format(file.FileName))
```

However I seem to be getting an error with permissions?

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "Cannot save the attachment. You don't have appropriate permission to perform this operation.", None, 0, -2147024891), None)
```

Not sure how to work around this, I am the Admin etc.

I am also wondering what would be the changes required to actually deploy this online and have it running, i.e. I am not passing any credentials as it's local, if operating stand alone I would like it to access my inbox every 7 days or so and download this specific attachments from this specific email.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose another drive or folder, for example, `My Documents` doesn't require admin privileges for writing. Otherwise, you will have to run Outlook with  admin privileges if you want to write anything to the system drive (C:).

Also I've  noticed the following lines of code:

```
mail_items = [item for item in inbox.Items if item.Class == 43]
filtered = [item for item in mail_items if item.Subject == target_subject]
```

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea, moreover, you are doing that twice!

I'd recommend using the `Find`/FindNext`or`Restrict` methods of the Items class that allow getting only items that correspond to the specified condition. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Answer (score 0):

Users by default do not have write access to the root drive (C:).
Change it to something like `'c:\temp\'`

Comment: The code (most likely) doesn't attempt to write to the root directory. It attempts to write to `C:some_file` (note the missing backslash). That's valid, though [unusual syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) for: Write to `some_file` in the current working directory of drive `C`. That's still either unintended or wrong.

Comment: `C:some_file` **is** in the root folder of the C:\ drive. And you cannot do that without elevation.

Comment: No, it isn't. This specific syntax involves the *current working directory*. `C:\some_file`, on the other hand, is in the root.

Comment: `'C:'.Format(someValue)` will produce `'C:' ` in Python, would it not? save_path should be something like` 'c:\SomeExistingFolder\{0}'`

Comment: Not sure, what you were trying to say. The markup certainly can get in the way.

Comment: I am saying the code (as written) is equivalent to `file.SaveAsFile('C:')`

Comment: No, it isn't. The code clearly appends to `C:`.

Comment: It does not. It calls Format on a string that contains no placeholder: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: Oh, I see, you changed your reasoning half way through the comments. Sure, that is correct, `'C:'.format('whatever')` produces the string `'C:'`. That names a volume, though, not a drive.